# Data gathering game that is only available to selected people

Tags: facebook, privacy, policy

**SUMMARY:**

- I'm making a free that will only run for 3-5 months or more.
- It will ask the user's info, most are not required, basic ones are. i.e. age/gender
- The information gathered will be used only for statistical data that will be used for a bigger game.
- I agree to anything Facebook wants on the page, not on the game.
- Only available to selected people.

**QUESTION:**

- Do any of the above violate any facebook policy? (If so, please point out an alternative)
- Does facebook provide a way that only a group can use an app?

---

**IN-DEPTH:**

I'm creating a game that is like a preliminary game for something bigger. It would ask the user to provide a LOT of info, including information not in facebook. Though most of them aren't required, only their facebook account login is required and some basic information like age/gender.

I'm not against the facebook putting ads or anything for that matter, just not on the game. The only thing I need is the information gathered from the game. After 3-5 months or more, the game will be pulled-out entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is violating a few of facebook's policies:

See http://developers.facebook.com/policy/

II - 1. : This one is debatable, but I'm pretty sure facebook won't agree that you need all those data to run your application, even if it's a survey app.

II - 6. : You are not allowed to transfer user data, even aggregated and/or anonymous.

II - 9 : Once again, you can't transfer the user data outside the application.

I don't see any alternative for you. If you want those data you will need to ask them inside the game itself, not on a separate application.
I f you don't want the facebook ads on your game, built the game a connect website.